# Best way to attach MDF Casing to

Tags: trim, mdf, trim-carpentry

So I purchased some of [This Here MDF Casing](http://houseoffara.com/products/casing/all/8203). And am trying to determine that best way to attach it to my raw lumber frame.

The basic choices Glue, Nails, or Screws come to mind.

I'd like to use just glue that way I don't have to go back and clean up the nail/screw holes with wood fill then need to patch paint it.

But is that really feasible? Or do I have to put ***ATLEAST*** a couple nails in anyways?

From what I am reading it seems most people only use nails to hold the MDF up while the glue cures. So, my thought is maybe I could just use some kind of special quick cure glue and forego the tacks?

This MDF is going to be attached to un-touched wood 2x3's if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nail it. You will forever regret a decision to glue the casing if it ever comes to a need to do repairs or modifications.

Comment: @MichaelKaras That was a thought I never had, removal could be huge factor.

Comment: @MichaelKaras that's an answer.

Comment: Copied comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nail it. You will forever regret a decision to glue the casing if it ever comes to a need to do repairs or modifications.